# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "admin"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

When I try to connect to my PostgreSQL server using my credentials using (pgadmin iii - postgres sqltool) it works fine. When I try to connect from my java application I get the below logs. It's weird

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "admin"
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:240)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy8.getCollegeDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.cts.bo.HESBO.registerCourse(HESBO.java:42)
    at com.cts.facade.HESFacade.registerCourse(HESFacade.java:34)
    at com.cts.manager.HESManager.registerCourse(HESManager.java:34)
    at com.cts.presentation.Tester.registerCourse(Tester.java:66)
    at com.cts.presentation.Tester.main(Tester.java:159)
**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "admin"**
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:415)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:188)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.<init>(Jdbc3gConnection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:412)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:202)
    ... 11 more
```

.properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

jdbc.password=admin
jdbc.username=admin
```

spring.xml

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>com\cts\resource\constant.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Any help on this is much appreciated, I am just not able to progress because of this weird error.

Comment: Please set `log_connections=on` in `postgresql.conf`, reload with `pg_ctl reload`, try again and post the message from the PostgreSQL server log.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested, set log_connections=on in postgresql.conf and executed the query SELECT pg_reload_conf(); which returned t. When i tried to connect from my application, the issue still exists. Any suggestions to make this work please?

Comment: Please post the message that the failed connection attempt produced in the PostgreSQL server log as I suggested.

Comment: I see the console printing the above logs posted in the query, did u mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean the [PostgreSQL server log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) and *not* the JVM output.

Comment: Sorry, please could u guide me as for how to enable postgres server logs and print them

Comment: Read the link in my above comment...

Comment: I have set log_connections=on in postgresql.conf, I am not sure on how to do the reload pg_ctl...

Comment: Log into the database server as PostgreSQL user and run `pg_ctl reload -D <data directory>`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem might be that the postgres database is configured to allow the only password that are hashed with md5.

You can check if this is true by going to the configuration file `pg_hba.conf`.
Search with the following property `host all all all`  if you find that the property is configured like below:

```
host all all all md5
```

than the issue is that you need to hash the password to md5. You can fix this by changing the configuration to:

- `trust` instead of `md5` -> will allow user to connect without any password
- `password` instead of `md5` -> will allow user to connect with plain text password

Comment: Conversely, is there is a "right way" to md5 hash the password so that it works with Postgres? Just any regular method of MD5 hashing is okay?

Comment: I think if you hash the password with MD5 it is going to work.

Comment: This worked: [ echo -n '<the password>' | md5sum ]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to **allow an IP or a range of IP addresses** to connect to PostgreSQL.

If you are using Docker, for example, the problem might be that you didn't allow the Docker network for PostgreSQL.

1. Get the host IP address on the Docker network interface (`ip addr show docker0  | grep 'inet'`);
2. Allow your IP addresses to connect to Postgre in `pg_hba.conf`.

> If you only want to allow an IP address, for instance, either use `/32` at the end of
> the address or write the `255.255.255.255` subnet mask after as shown
> bellow:
>
> ```
> host    all     all     172.17.0.1        255.255.255.255     md5
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> host    all     all     172.17.0.1/32     md5
> ```

Read [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for more information on the structure of the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user under Login section and using that in application.properties, solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, although I was running the PostgreSQL server inside a Docker container. I fixed it by using a different port mapping (e.g. 0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp).

Symptoms and debugging:

- The error message was "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user xxx".
- Changing JDBC host, port or username resulted in a different error message.
- PgAdmin was able to connect to the database.
- PgAdmin connections were shown in the PostgreSQL log (after enabling connection logging), but nothing was shown when trying to connect with JDBC.
- `tcpdump port 5432` showed nothing when trying to connect with JDBC, but showed something when connecting with PgAdmin, or when sending random data with netcat.

In the end the root cause remained unclear. But obviously it was not a password problem, so the JDBC driver shouldn't say it is.

Docker version 20.10.17 running on Windows 10. PostgreSQL driver version was 42.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

For me, its worked when i updated the version

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>42.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```