# can not connect postgres in spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, spring-boot, jpa

I am beginer with java and Spring boot and when i build simple project to connect with postgres but it not work. 
here my struct of project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF0s2.png)

here my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>me.loda.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-learning</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-learning</name>
    <description>Everything about Spring Boot</description>

    <dependencies>

        <!--spring mvc, rest-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring jpa-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mysql connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <configuration>
                    <mainClass>app6.App6</mainClass>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here my application.properties file:

```
## default connection pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5

## PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring
spring.datasource.username=spring    
spring.datasource.password=spring
```

here my main file:

```
import app6.*;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@SpringBootApplication
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class App6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App6.class, args);
        UserRepository userRepository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);

        // Lấy ra toàn bộ user trong db
        userRepository.findAll()
                      .forEach(System.out::println);

        // Lưu user xuống database
        User user = userRepository.save(new User());
        // Khi lưu xong, nó trả về User đã lưu kèm theo Id.
        System.out.println("User vừa lưu có ID: " + user.getId());
        Long userId = user.getId();
        // Cập nhật user.
        user.setAge(100);
        // Update user
        // Lưu ý, lúc này đối tượng user đã có Id. 
        // Nên nó sẽ update vào đối tượng có Id này 
        // chứ không insert một bản ghi mới
        userRepository.save(user);

        // Query lấy ra user vừa xong để kiểm tra xem.
        User user2 = userRepository.findById(userId).get();
        System.out.println("User: " + user);
        System.out.println("User2: " + user2);

        // Xóa User khỏi DB
        userRepository.delete(user);

        // In ra kiểm tra xem userId còn tồn tại trong DB không
        User user3 = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null);
        System.out.println("User3: " + user2);

    }

}
```

User.java:

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data 
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -297553281792804396L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name =  "name")
    private String name;

    private int age;

    private String email;

}
```

UserRepository.java:

```
package app6;


import java.util.List;
import app6.User;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findAllByAtk(int atk);
}
```

and my log when i run project:

```
[INFO] ----------------< me.loda.spring:spring-boot-learning >-----------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-learning 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ spring-boot-learning >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/meo/Documents/mydocuments/20191/project/test/test6/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/meo/Documents/mydocuments/20191/project/test/test6/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/meo/Documents/mydocuments/20191/project/test/test6/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ spring-boot-learning <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ spring-boot-learning ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)

2019-11-18 23:37:26.626  INFO 5431 --- [           main] app6.App6                                : Starting App6 on meo-Latitude-E6540 with PID 5431 (/home/meo/Documents/mydocuments/20191/project/test/test6/target/classes started by meo in /home/meo/Documents/mydocuments/20191/project/test/test6)
2019-11-18 23:37:26.638  INFO 5431 --- [           main] app6.App6                                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-18 23:37:27.323  INFO 5431 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-11-18 23:37:27.372  INFO 5431 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 42ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-11-18 23:37:27.584  INFO 5431 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-11-18 23:37:27.786  INFO 5431 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-11-18 23:37:27.798  INFO 5431 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-11-18 23:37:27.798  INFO 5431 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-11-18 23:37:27.883  INFO 5431 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-11-18 23:37:27.884  INFO 5431 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1169 ms
2019-11-18 23:37:27.988  INFO 5431 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-11-18 23:37:28.156 ERROR 5431 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "spring    "
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:520) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]

        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
      org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at app6.App6.main(App6.java:14) ~[classes/:na]

2019-11-18 23:37:28.178  INFO 5431 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2019-11-18 23:37:28.223  INFO 5431 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.6.Final}
2019-11-18 23:37:28.328  INFO 5431 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2019-11-18 23:37:28.402  INFO 5431 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-11-18 23:37:28.424 ERROR 5431 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "spring    "
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:520) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:458) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260) ~[postgresql-42.2.8.jar:42.2.8]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:931) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at app6.App6.main(App6.java:14) ~[classes/:na]

2019-11-18 23:37:28.425  WARN 5431 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "spring    "
2019-11-18 23:37:28.427  WARN 5431 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2019-11-18 23:37:28.430  INFO 5431 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-11-18 23:37:28.443  INFO 5431 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-18 23:37:28.451 ERROR 5431 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]


        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at app6.App6.main(App6.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:931) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.6.Final.jar:5.4.6.Final]
        ... 33 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.161 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-18T23:37:28+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-boot-learning: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Sombody con help me??

Comment: It looks like your username is set to `spring    ` instead of just `spring`.  Does it work if you remove those extra spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
Are Your UserName and Password Correct Did u try to connect this username and password in postgress client if not please try .


Please visit Below Link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427407/caused-by-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-fatal-password-authentication-fai
```